# Express SQL UNION query Rails way

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, arel

I got a query which works well, but expressed in SQL. I would like to have the same query expressed using ActiveRecord Query Interface (Arel would also do fine). The query should preferably return ActiveRecord::Relation or, at least, it's result should be convertible to an array of Customer models.

The goal is to fetch `company's` `customers` having no associated `import_logs` with `remote_type = 'account'`, as well as `customers` having an `import_log` with `remote_type = 'account'` and `status = 'pending'`.

A `customer` can have no `import_logs` associated at all, or have an `import_log` per each `remote_type`, or only for some `remote_types`. There can be only one associated `import_log` with specific `remote_type` value.

This reflects a requirement that a `customer` can be imported as `account` or `contact` or both and `import_log` tracks the status of the import.

Although `import_log` has a polymorphic association with `customer`, this is not relevant to the task.

Existing query:

```
Customer.find_by_sql(
  <<-SQL
    SELECT
      customers.*
    FROM
      customers
    WHERE
      company_id = #{@company.id}
      AND NOT EXISTS
          ( SELECT *
            FROM import_logs
            WHERE import_logs.importable_id = customers.id
              AND import_logs.importable_type = 'Customer'
              AND import_logs.remote_type = 'account'
          )
    UNION
    SELECT
      customers.*
    FROM
      customers,
      import_logs
    WHERE
      import_logs.importable_id = customers.id AND
      import_logs.importable_type = 'Customer' AND
      company_id = #{@company.id} AND
      import_logs.remote_type = 'account' AND
      import_logs.status = 'pending';
  SQL
)
```

Relevant portions of ImportLog model:

```
create_table "import_logs", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "importable_id"
  t.string   "importable_type"
  t.string   "status",          default: "pending", null: false
  t.string   "remote_type"
  ...
end

add_index "import_logs", ["importable_id", "importable_type", "remote_type"], unique: true ...

class ImportLog < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :importable, polymorphic: true
  ...
end
```

Relevant portions of Customer model:

```
create_table "customers", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "company_id"
  ...
end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :import_logs, as: :importable
  ...
end
```

And of Company model, just in case:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :customers
  ...
end
```

Comment: The second query in your union seems odd to me. Missing a join maybe. Or `EXISTS`. I wonder if it even does what is intended.

Comment: The second query fetches `customers` having an `import_log` present. Its top `WHERE` condition is synonymous with `INNER JOIN` so it's style difference. It does work as intended.

Comment: It's just that Rails typically fetches associations through `INNER JOIN`s. All right, I see the logic behind it. The only problem then is a `UNION`. I have to think for a while. In the meantime, check out [`scuttle.io`](http://scuttle.io/) that might give some hints on where to start.

Comment: Scuttle.io trips on this query. This is something I checked before posting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `merge` associations

In fact, there is only one assocation that is driven by a query constant.

```
"customers"."company_id" = #{@company.id}
```

It's the same as:

```
.merge(@company.customers)
```

...and this looks a bit safer and more sensible

#### Arel tables

We'll need it soon.

```
customers = Customer.arel_table
```

#### `NOT EXISTS ...` subquery

Arel can do that, the only not-so-obvious thing is how to reference the outside table:

```
ne_subquery = ImportLog.where(
                importable_type: Customer.to_s,
                  importable_id: customers[:id],
                    remote_type: 'account'
              ).exists.not
```

This results in a hunk of Arel AST we can feed to Rails' `where`-statement.

#### Now both queries become obvious:

```
first  = @company.customers.where(ne_subquery)
second = @company.customers.joins(:import_logs).merge(
           ImportLog.where(
           # importable_id: customers[:id], # `joins` already does it
           importable_type: Customer.to_s,
               remote_type: 'acoount',
                    status: 'pending'
           )
         )
```

That is pretty much a 1-to-1 conversion.

#### Union

That is a tricky part, and the only solution I have found has terribly ugly syntax and outputs a bit different query. Given `A union B` we can only build `select X.* from (A union B) X`. The effect is the same.

All right, let's get to it:

```
Customer.from(
  customers.create_table_alias(
    first.union(second),
    Customer.table_name
  )
)
```

Of course, to make this query more readable, you should:

- Place it as a scope in `Customer` class
- Split out reusable parts into scopes and associations

Comment: Thanks for the effort! This all works to the point of making the union. At that it trips with this message: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::ProtocolViolation: ERROR:  bind message supplies 0 parameters, but prepared state
ment "" requires 1`. Apparently, `company_id` does not get bound and I haven't yet found a way to fix that.

Comment: A dirty way would be to apply the condition on `company_id` yourself in a `where`-call instead of delegating it to the association. Well, that **would work**. I just don't like that style.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, could you give an example?

Comment: I can try. What is the SQL that results in this error?

Comment: Uhm... that's odd, two `$1`s. Looks like you'll have to bind a value yourself. I'm not sure how to do that, but I'll take a look. What would probably work is a separate where-clause with a condition string. Try that one out.

Comment: I wonder if Arel is to blame for that or AR's shortcuts. Duh.

Comment: Two `$1`s in fact expected since same `company_id` filter is used within two queries. Separate `where` clause doesn't help since it is what it is, a separate clause. It gets bound to `$2` placeholder. The question is how to bind to `company_id` value to the original `$1`.

Comment: @NicNilov a condition **string** might make a difference since it allows you to bind the value differently (i. e. by `?` or `:key`).

Comment: In a generic case, two `$1`s is a bug, those could have been different companies. Arel does no optimisations such as reducing duplicates, as far as I know. It's just plain Ruby-to-SQL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80757/discussion-between-nic-nilov-and-d-side).

Comment: I'm accepting the answer since it does push forward to the solution. I strongly suspect there is an issue in ActiveRecord which manifests in `$1` placeholders assigned incorrectly. I will post more in case I got more info on this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code suggested by @D-side I was able to reach a working solution. Here is the initially suggested code:

```
customers = Customer.arel_table

ne_subquery = ImportLog.where(
  importable_type: Customer.to_s,
  importable_id: customers['id'],
  remote_type: 'account'
).exists.not

first  = @company.customers.where(ne_subquery)
second = @company.customers.joins(:import_logs).merge(
  ImportLog.where(
    importable_type: Customer.to_s,
    remote_type: 'account',
    status: 'pending'
  )
)

Customer.from(
  customers.create_table_alias(
    first.union(second),
    Customer.table_name
  )
)
```

Running it leads to this error:

```
PG::ProtocolViolation: ERROR:  bind message supplies 0 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 1

: SELECT "customers".* FROM ( SELECT "customers".* FROM "customers"  WHERE "customers"."company_id" = $1 \
AND (NOT (EXISTS (SELECT "import_logs".* FROM "import_logs"  WHERE "import_logs"."importable_type" = 'Customer' \
AND "import_logs"."importable_id" = "customers"."id"))) UNION SELECT "customers".* FROM "customers" \
INNER JOIN "import_logs" ON "import_logs"."importable_id" = "customers"."id" \
AND "import_logs"."importable_type" = 'Customer' WHERE "customers"."company_id" = $1 \
AND "import_logs"."importable_type" = 'Customer' AND "import_logs"."remote_type" = 'contact' \
AND "import_logs"."status" = 'pending' ) "customers"
```

This error I believe is a manifestation of [Rails issue #20077](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/20077) which at this time stands unresolved. Since the issue relates to parameter binding, making that binding more explicit helps. Here is a working solution:

```
customers = Customer.arel_table

ne_subquery = ImportLog.where(
  importable_type: Customer.to_s,
  importable_id: customers['id'],
  remote_type: 'account'
).exists.not

first  = Customer.where(ne_subquery).where(company_id: @company.id)
second = Customer.joins(:import_logs).merge(
  ImportLog.where(
    importable_type: Customer.to_s,
    remote_type: 'account',
    status: 'pending'
  )
).where(company_id: @company.id)

Customer.from(
  customers.create_table_alias(
    first.union(second),
    Customer.table_name
  )
)
```

Note the `.where(company_id: @company.id)` are applied explicitly and `first` and `second` queries begin unscoped.